# Ubuntu 14.04 Diskless Workstation

Tags: dhcp, nfs, ltsp, tftp, ltsp-client

I already follow all step given from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) but when I try to boot the client using network it reply:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: EC B1 D7 4F E5 C1  GUID: 80763A3E B448 E511 8E7C ECB1D74FE5C1
CLIENT IP: 192.168.10.101 MASK: 255.255.255.0 DHCP IP: 192.168.10.50
GATEWAY IP: 192.168.10.1
TFTP.
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent
```

What should I do?